# Laravel 8 - Request does not retrive input field

Tags: php, laravel

I am using **Laravel 8**. I have the following search box in my blade file:

```html
<form name="searchForm" class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3" method="POST" action="{{ url('search')  }}">
    @csrf
    <input name="searchField" type="search" class="form-control form-control-dark" style="width: 426px; " placeholder="Search for news, symbols, tickers or companies">
</form>
```

I route this to my `SearchController`:

```php
public function showSearchPage(Request $request) {
    $field = $request->searchField;
    $name = Input::get('searchField');
    .
    .
    .
```

However, `$request->searchField` is null. My `$request` object looks like the following:

[image]

Besides the token, my input field is not within the `request`.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: change the `form` attribute of your form to `id` and try the form attribute on the input field

Comment: @Aless55 Thx this works. Do I need `name` and `id` both or only `id`? Haven`t found any specific about this in the documentation. Please add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `form` attribute of your form to `id` and try the `form` attribute on the input field.

Normally you shouldn't have to define either of those, you might try removing the `id` from your form and also the `form` from the input field.
It is possible that the initial `form` attribute on your form caused some trouble.

Let me know if the second approach also worked.

Answer (score 2):

What I know is that, use form id when you need to perform a validation for a script or you have multiple forms in a single page, try changing your form attribute to id, or better if you completely remove it

Answer (score 1):

for search form its better to use **GET** method instead of **POST**
and instead of
type="search"
used
type="text" (for test)

Answer (score 1):

added id="searchField" to your input and changed type to text form search. should work

```
<form name="searchForm" class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3" method="POST" action="{{ url('search')  }}">
    @csrf
    <input name="searchField" id="searchField" type="text" class="form-control form-control-dark" style="width: 426px; " placeholder="Search for news, symbols, tickers or companies">
</form>
```